# change type of Object depending on method argument

Tags: java, object, types, forge

So once again, sorry this questian might be answered/asked a lot allready, but I'm not really sure what i am searching for

I'm currently making a mod for a game and need to register custom items i created.
I created custom classes for every type of item which contain various variables I need to access. The problem is, the class(es) they all inherit from does not have these variables/data.

My initial attempt was something like this (pseudo code'ish)

```
public void addItem(Item itemc)
{
   Object item = null;
     if (itemc.getClass().equals(ItemTool))
          item = (ItemTool) itemc;
      if (itemc.getClass().equals(ItemFood))
          item = (ItemFood) itemc;
        .......etc..........

    registerItem(item,item.name);
    registerItemRenderer(item,item.meta,item.model);
}
```

But that doesn't work and i get an error saying item (treated as an Object as initialized) does not have these members.

Right now i just overloaded the method addItem to accept every custom item class i made (over 10 atm), but thats not really what i want.

Is there a way to change the type of an Object to whatever class i will pass as argument and then work with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the extraction of `item.name` into the `if`:

```
Object item = null;
Object itemName = null;

if (itemc.getClass().equals(ItemTool)) {
    item = (ItemTool) itemc;
    itemName = item.name;
} else {
    if (itemc.getClass().equals(ItemFood)) {
        item = (ItemFood) itemc;
        itemName = item.name;
    }
}

registerItem(item, itemName);
```

but it would be far more OO-like to create an `Interface` for `Item` to include a `getName`-method which every `Item` implements and your method does not have to know which type your item is to obtain the name:

```
public void addItem(Item item) {
    registerItem(item, item.getName());
}
```

Comment: Since i cannot modify the actually game files (which the Item class is part of) i cannot create an interface for Item.
I could potentially clone the Item class and implement the interface, but since Item is pretty "far down" in the inheritance i would have to clone a lot of other Classes which is not what i want, so i guess i have to use your first method - which is still pretty "ugly", but it works. Thanks

Comment: If you can't change the game files, you could at least create a new `GameItem` encapsulating items if you would have to dispatch behavior based on the `Item` class on more situations than only the one above - according to the "Adapter" pattern.